# vbs script to search for specific directory names and create a "Trash" folder when search = true

Tags: search, vbscript, mkdir

I need to create a script that when run, searches for directories called "3. Max" and "4. Render Output". If the search equals true, a new directory is created within it called "Trash"

I've found many mkdir examples but non will achieve what I need to do.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) has methods to

1. check for a folder's existence (.FolderExists)
2. create a folder, given the full path (.CreateFolder)

and the .Subfolders collection to iterate over a folder's children. Use this info to come up with a plan (included **detailed** specs), publish it and ask **specific** questions, when you are faced with problems.